# Links shown in spoilers when looking at revisions

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list, spoilers

Even when nothing's being modified, links are shown through spoilers when looking at the non-markdown output of a revision. This happens both when reviewing edits and when looking at the revision history like normal. And it looks weird.

Here's what it looks like when [reviewing an edit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/33877) (and nothing changed in the spoiler):

[image]

And [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/64969/revisions) is an example of revision history where you can see this on one of my answers. Some of the spoiler blocks there were modified, so you can see what it looks like for comparison.

Comment: It looks like SE made some big changes to the spoiler markup. The modifications performed by the SOUP user script seem to no longer work, either.